# Move a sprite between two points [back and forth continuously]

Tags: c#, xna

I'm pretty new to XNA|C# and what I want to do is simply move a sprite between two points and have it move back and forth continuously.

Let's say I want the sprite to move between the y-coordinate 100 and 0.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with XNA itself. You are asking how to move an object in a straight line and that is something that is usually learnt in first year geometry.

I'll assume you are drawing your texture like this:

```
SpriteTexture sprite;
Vector2 position;
...
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, position, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

A straight line is an extremely simple path - it is easily defined by two points. Let the points be P1 and P2. The straight line is then defined as the function `(1 - t) * P1 + t * P2` where `0 <= t <= 1`. To move the sprite, start from `t = 0` and increment `t` in each update cycle. Computing the function with the given `t` gives you the position of the sprite. When `t >= 1` you've reached P2, this means you should start decrementing `t` back to 0 and so on and so forth. Here's how to use that fact to move the sprite:

```
SpriteTexture sprite;
Vector2 position;
Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(0, 100), 
        p2 = new Vector2(0, 0);
double currentTime = 0, timestep = 0.01;
...    
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
   position = currentTime * p1 + (1 - currentTime) * p2;
   currentTime += timestep;
   if (currentTime >= 1 || currentTime <= 0)
   {
       timestep *= -1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how XNA works, every frame it calls the methods update and draw in your game's main page. We need to keep track of which direction your sprite is moving and its position so lets add to your main game file:

```
public Vector2 rectanglePosition = new Vector2(0,0);
public bool moveRight = true;
```

Now what you want to do is every frame update the position, and use it to draw an object. So in the update method you would have something like

```
if (moveRight)  
rectanglePosition.Y += 10;  
else  
rectanglePosition.Y -= 10; 

if(rectanglePosition.Y>100 || rectanglePosition.Y<0) 
moveRight = !moveright;
```

Then in the draw method just draw the sprite based on the position (you can start by just drawing a rectangle), which you can look up how to do easily.

I can further help you if you don't get the code.